# Non-PDF special ignored! -- TeXLive / PSTricks / OSX Mac

Tags: pdftex, pstricks

I'm using TeXLive with OSX/Mac, and building with `latexmk`.  I need three (3) vertical lines spanning the entire page (inside the margins), and one (1) vertical line of numbers 1 through 28 (inside the margin -- manually typed, not auto line numbering).  The internet searches I found relating to my error messages ("Non-PDF special ignored!") discussed putting a `[pdf]` between usepackage and pstricks (i.e., `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}`, or adding `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`.  And, to use a command line of `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>` or `pdflatex -enable-write18 <file>`.

Well, I've tried every combination I could think of in terms of using a command line with the suggested options, and I've tried varying the above packages -- all to no avail.  The document sometimes builds correctly (even with the error messages); however, sometimes the *.pdf has errors in the region of the marginnotes.  Any ideas on how to eliminate the error messages, and build the document correctly?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=.65in, left=1in, right=.5in, marginparwidth=8mm, marginparsep=5mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\else
\usepackage{pstricks}
\fi    

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \doublespacing
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{\centering}
\reversemarginpar

\newcommand{\pleading}{\marginnote{\doublespacing 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \\ 7 \\ 8 \\ 9 \\ 10 \\ 11 \\ 12 \\ 13 \\ 14 \\ 15 \\ 16 \\ 17 \\ 18 \\ 19 \\ 20 \\ 21 \\ 22 \\ 23 \\ 24 \\ 25 \\ 26 \\ 27 \\ 28} }

% BEGIN left and right vertical lines, and marginnote.
\newlength{\leftruleA}
\setlength{\leftruleA}{3.2\leftmargin-\marginparsep}

\newlength{\leftruleB}
\setlength{\leftruleB}{3.0\leftmargin-\marginparsep}

\newlength{\rightrule}
\setlength{\rightrule}{2.6\leftmargin+\textwidth+\marginparsep}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \put(\LenToUnit{\leftruleA},0){\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}  % First rule on the left
    \put(\LenToUnit{\leftruleB},0){\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}  % Second rule on the left
    \put(\LenToUnit{\rightrule},0){\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}  % Rule on the right
    \rput(1,25.23){\pleading} % second numeric figure is the top positioning of the marginnote.
 }
}
% END left and right vertical lines, and marginnote.

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The _warning_ you get is not anything to necessarily be concerned about. What we will need is a minimal example to give more guidance.

Answer (score 5):

the warning message can be ignored. It happens always when loading a PostScript related package and running pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

you can prevent the warning with:

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\else
  \usepackage{pstricks}
\fi
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: Emergency Stop!  I'm adding a minimal working example to the initial post.  Here are the two lines of code that are referenced as the culprit:  `\rput(1,25.23){\pleading}` and `\newcommand{\pleading}{\marginnote{\doublespacing 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \\ 7 \\ 8 \\ 9 \\ 10 \\ 11 \\ 12 \\ 13 \\ 14 \\ 15 \\ 16 \\ 17 \\ 18 \\ 19 \\ 20 \\ 21 \\ 22 \\ 23 \\ 24 \\ 25 \\ 26 \\ 27 \\ 28} }`

Comment: Undefined control sequence.  <argument> ...){\rule {1pt}{\paperheight }} \rput (1,25.23){\pleading }

Comment: @lawlist: see my edited answer. It was only an example for the warning message. For your example you have to load `auto-pst-pdf`

Comment: Are there alternative pdflatex user-friendly package(s) that can give me the vertical lines and vertical numbers 1 to 28?  I've made the modification as suggested (i.e., to include `auto-pst-pdf`), and the minimal working example has been updated.  Unfortunately, I'm still getting some error messages with the minimal working example; and, the full version cannot complete (even using force).

Comment: Alternatively, I guess I could just leave it the way it was and use the `-silent` or `-quiet` command.  Perhaps what I don't know won't hurt me?  It's the OCDC in me that wants a flawless run, but perhaps not seeing the error messages would give me peace of mind?

Comment: @lawlist: use `xelatex` then you do not need the package `auto-pst-pdf`

Comment: I'll give that a try.